# Why if I have 3 animation clips in the Animation component but when I iterate over the clips in script it's finding only two?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Animation clips]

The script :

```
var distance = Vector3.Distance(crate.position, player.position);
        if (distance < 1.7f && crateOpenOnce == false)
        {
            List<AnimationState> states = new List<AnimationState>();
            foreach (AnimationState state in anim)
            {
                states.Add(state);
            }

            anim.Play(states[2].name);

            crateOpenOnce = true;
        }
```

When I'm using a breakpoint on the line :

```
anim.Play(states[2].name);
```

I see that states contains only 2 items the first two animation clips the open and close.

Comment: Does it throw error? states[2] is third animation, so if there are only two, then this line would throw error.

Comment: What does [`GetClipCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.GetClipCount.html) return?

Comment: In the end, I will use Animator for playing it.  It does give an error I just wonder it counts only the 2 animations.